# SELECT only TOP value using WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

In my SQLFiddle [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a9e7/3/0)

I'm trying to `SELECT` `ROW`s `WHERE` `i.id` = `1` with the highest `value`, Then `i.id = 2` and so on.

So here in my Query

```
SELECT
i.`item`, v.`nom`, v.`value`
FROM `items` i
LEFT JOIN `values` v ON v.`item_id` = i.`id`
WHERE
i.`id` IS NOT NULL 
  AND
CASE
  WHEN i.`id` = 1 THEN 1
  WHEN i.`id` = 2 THEN 2
  ELSE 3
END
ORDER BY 
CASE
  WHEN i.`id` = 1 THEN 1
  WHEN i.`id` = 2 THEN 2
  ELSE 3
END
, v.`value` DESC;
```

I get the rows

```
item    nom     value
C1      C12     7
C1      C11     4
C2      C21     9
C2      C22     8
C4      C41     44
C4      C42     13
C5      C52     12
C5      C51     8
C3      C31     3
C3      C32     2
```

But what I want to get is only the `TOP` values, So it becomes

```
item    nom     value
C1      C12     7
C2      C21     9
C4      C41     44
```

To clear it more, I want to `SELECT` each `TOP` values for each `i.id`,

Then I `SELECT` after `SELECT`ing the 3 specific `i.id`s the Highest `TOP` value in the `Table` itself,

Just in case none of the 3 `i.id`s exists.

How can I do that? Is the Query overall Good or Bad? Can I optimize it more?

I'm not trying to retrieve the **Last Record** by ID, But the highest record by value, Something like

```
SELECT
i.`item`, v.`nom`, v.`value`
FROM `items` i
LEFT JOIN `values` v ON v.`item_id` = i.`id`
WHERE
i.`id` IS NOT NULL 
  AND
CASE
  WHEN i.`id` = 1 AND TOP(v.`value`) THEN 1
  WHEN i.`id` = 2 AND TOP(v.`value`) THEN 2
  ELSE TOP(v.`value`) 3
END
ORDER BY 
CASE
  WHEN i.`id` = 1 THEN 1
  WHEN i.`id` = 2 THEN 2
  ELSE 3
END
```